# HttpPost response "BadRequest" in Blazor Webassembly hosted model

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

I am sending a HttpPost request to a blazor webassembly hosted and I am getting a response with a status code "BadRequest".

Here is my `HttpClient` service (`ChatService`):

```cs
public ChatService(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    _httpClient = httpClient;
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
        MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}

// This method works without problem
public async Task<List<ApplicationUser>> GetUsersAsync()
{
    var data = await 
        _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<ApplicationUser>> 
        ("api/chat/users");
    return data;
}

// This one returns a BadRequest response
public async Task SaveMessageAsync(ChatMessage message)
{
    
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/chat", message);

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BadRequest");
    }
}
```

And here is my `ApiController` endpoint:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class ChatController : ControllerBase
{   
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveMessageAsync(ChatMessage message)
    {
        // Save the message in DB
    }
}
```

Is there anything that I forgot to configure that is making my post request get rejected?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure that "api/chat" calls SaveMessageAsync?

Comment: Yes i doubled checked the name! The response is BadRequest

Comment: [polite] I just edited the post to sort out the code formatting.  Please revew the code you have presented as it won't compile as is.

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the controller on the first line of `SaveMessageAsync`.  Check it'a getting hit on the call.  Also what does `ChatMessage` look like?

Comment: It does not hit the controller in SaveMessageAsync!
Here is how my ChatMessage looks like :
     ```Id : 0
        FromUserId : '213-dfc-frr'
        ToUserId : '765-fcr-dbc'
        Message : 'Hello'
        CreatedDate : 19/03/2023 16:07:37
        FromUser : null
        ToUser : null
       ```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why i was getting a BadRequest,
It's because the object(ChatMessage) that i was sending to the Api had null values for field that were declared not nullable, so i changed my entity ChatMessage to allow null values for (ApplicationUser's) like the following :

```
    public class ChatMessage
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string FromUserId { get; set; }
        public string ToUserId { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser? FromUser { get; set; }//this was not nullable before
        public virtual ApplicationUser? ToUser { get; set; } //this was not nullable before
    }
```

Now i am able to hit the endpoint "SaveMessageAsync"